# Xamarin Android debugging: No compatible code running

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Context**

I am using VS 2017.3 to develop Xamarin.Forms application. I am trying to diagnose where and why an Exception occur on my code.

I can successfully deploy run and debug my application using the SDK Android Emulator (HAX x86).

However in case an Exception occur I can not see any information about the Exception, see attached picture, settings.

**Question**

Is this normal in Android debugging, or missing I something?

[image]

...and my build settings:

[image]

Comment: It is not a **managed** exception, it is crashing in native code (Android runtime, mono runtime, native library, ....)

Comment: well, then quite misleading the message offers to open Exception Settings which has nothing to do with this...

Comment: Hello, did you find out how to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 10):

I wanted to expand on @Uraitz's answer because it helped me figure out the problem.

First, as he explains, you will want to add an event handler in your activity, as shown in the following code:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ...
        //subscribe to unhandled event  
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainUnhandledException;
        ...
    }

    private void CurrentDomainUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
```

In my case I put a breakpoint inside `CurrentDomainUnhandledException` so I could inspect the exception.

However, even with that breakpoint in there, I ran my code and still got a confusing no-callstack error.

[image]

At this point I thought the solution wasn't working. In fact it is, but I had to click the Play (continue) button multiple times before my app would hit the breakpoint:

[image]

After clicking that button **two times**, I finally hit the breakpoint:

[image]

If you want to get the callstack in the debugger, you will have to dive in a few levels before it is available, but you can do so by looking at the event args parameter.

[image]

The moral of the story is - if you have added the event handler but you still aren't hitting the breakpoint (or seeing output) - keep clicking the Continue button!

Answer (score 6):

Just continue, then look through the Output, it will show you the stack trace of the exception. It is a good idea to learn how to read through the log files to find information about exceptions.

Comment: Can you copy the output into a paste so we can have a look. Might see something you cant.

Answer (score 5):

You can subscribe on each platform main constructor to UnhandledException event this will give you more information about exception before break debug.

for example in Android:

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{

            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            //subscribe to unhandled event  
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;


            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
}

        private void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
}
```

If you need each platform explanation ask for them :)

Comment: you should go debugging step by step to find what code block you have without try/catch which is crashing app.

Comment: :-(. I though we are in 2017. Yes and also I can write my code in vi.

Comment: Have you added compiler options?
`using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
...
[XamlCompilation (XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public class HomePage : ContentPage
{
...`

Answer (score 4):

Deleting the bin and obj folders solved it in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I got similar issue, after investigating, I just have to disable the **Xamarin Inspector**.

[image]

Comment: I don't have this section in my settings

Comment: @Chucky - Its an [option in Enterprise version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/inspector/install?tabs=windows).

Answer (score 0):

Ill just throw this in the mix.
I was getting a "No compatible code running" error when attempting to break on otherwise 'working' code.

After struggling with this I decided to go back to an older version of visual studio where it didn't happening.
This gave me the idea to reset my Exception settings, and then the issue went away.

Seemingly there are a number of handled exceptions that any given library might be throwing, and if you choose to break on a particular condition you may well see this.