# Xamarin Unit Test Error "No compatible code running - the selected debug engine does not support any code running on this current thread"

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin

I am trying to unit test(nunit) my Portable library in Xamarin, but I am getting this error:

> No compatible code running - "the selected debug engine does not support any code running on this current thread"

Even If I try with `try/catch` block it still stops the debugging and throws the same error and after that it crashes.

**Update 1**

Similar question has been asked here [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344434/xamarin-android-debugging-no-compatible-code-running/46344556#46344556) and by @katxalot answer, I can see what is the problem (ArgumentOutOfRangeException) but what to do after that I don't know. I can see in output window that my unit test is passed but how to prevent the unit test emulator crashing?

Comment: I am getting this exception even there is ArgumentOutOfRangeException in my ViewModel code. 
Getting the exception if any exception occurs in ViewModel.

Comment: I am using unit test app (android) template for unit testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same error before.

Fix : If you have a breakpoint on await code block, you must put another breakpoint to next line. When i post an image to WebAPI from xamarin i get same error. But i was put a second breakpoint on the next line. Error is gone. This solution worked for me.

- Error [One breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iXUJ.png)
- Error is gone
  [Second breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO8DX.png)

The other fix : You have bad codes in your code file and the compiler could not debugging. You must find it and delete it