# How can I go about diagnosing a problem with Visual Studio being unable to break in a specific code block?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2022

I'm creating an app for android through Visual Studio 2022 Community version 17.6.4 (Xamarin).

I keep encountering this "No compatible code running on thread" error when I try to debug any content within this code block:

[image: "No compatible code running on thread"]

```
public bool OnNavigationItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
{
  int id = item.ItemId;

  if (id == Resource.Id.nav_camera)
  {
    int i = 5;
    int x = 3;
    if (i > x) //I like to put the break point in here to test if I'm going into this function.
    x += i; //I am going into the function, but I can't see the debugger due to the error page.
    // Handle the camera action
  }
  else if (id == Resource.Id.nav_gallery)
  {
  
  }
  else if (id == Resource.Id.nav_slideshow)
  {
  
  }
  else if (id == Resource.Id.nav_manage)
  {

  }
  else if (id == Resource.Id.nav_share)
  {

  }
  else if (id == Resource.Id.nav_send)
  {

  }

  DrawerLayout drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
  drawer.CloseDrawer(GravityCompat.Start);
  return true;
}
```

I've troubleshot answers of similar problems from [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344434/xamarin-android-debugging-no-compatible-code-running) especially hopeful of the last answer of restoring exception settings to default as it is the same error. But the same error occurs, and I'm new so can't comment to that user to ask if he/she ever solved their issue.

I can recreate this error by creating a new project for android (tablet and phone), and selecting the Navigation Drawer App template. I add whatever code I'd like (or don't) and put a breakpoint within OnNavigationItemSelected(IMenuItem item) and I encounter this error. This is the only function within the project I have this error.

Things I've tried:

- Enabling "Enable Just My Code" in debug settings
- Placing a breakpoint within a separate function present within OnNavigationItemSelected.
- Rolling back VS
- Deleted hidden .vs folder and .bin and .obj folders & uninstalled app from tablet.

Comment: the image you posted doesn't show any error

Comment: 10 What Visual Studio version?  2) Is this a debug build, or a release build?  3) Did you build with [code optimization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/optimizing-your-code?view=msvc-170) enabled?

Comment: @Jason I've corrected it I believe.

Comment: @dbc Visual Studio 2022 Community 17.6.4, debug build.

Comment: Maybe a code caching problem: delete hidden .vs folder and .bin and .obj folders, then build again.

Comment: I've tried deleting those folders to no avail.

Comment: Debug mode downloads code to android device/emulator, to communicate with debugger. Delete app from device, to clear that. Or Factory Reset.

Comment: I went ahead and uninstalled it from my tablet, deleted all 3 folders, built and ran it and encountered the same issue.

Comment: I also tested it on cleanly made virtual tablet, same issue.

Comment: I'm still troubleshooting this problem. I think it may be because native language is running when I enter this function, I could be  wrong.

Comment: I agree. UI code does involve native code (of the android control corresponding to the Xamarin element) calling back to xamarin internal code, that then calls your c# code. For whatever reason, this sometimes confuses debugger's ability to locate the c# code corresponding to the breakpoint. I had hoped that queueing it with BeginInvokeOnMainThread (as in answer I deleted) would get it to a state where it could find the breakpoint. But that didn't. In my experience, if cleaning both VS project and the emulator doesn't fix it, then its not fixable.

Comment: @toolmakerSteve the thing is other people have taken my project and debugged it with no issues. I don't know if I should let that give me hope or not, but I don't understand why I specifically have an issue where as others don't.

Comment: Things to try: Make a new emulator. Or attach an actual phone. Download source files (ONLY) to a new folder, for a clean start. Manually copy the entire built solution from a working pc (source/obj/bin - everything). Delete all versions of VS, reboot, reinstall latest. Maybe something else running on PC? Task manager / startup / turn off everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was answered in a follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76613675/how-can-i-determine-which-thread-is-running-native-code-vs-managed-code-in-visua) by liyun Zhang - MSFT
It had to do with outdated NuGet packages.