# How can I determine which thread is running native code vs managed code in visual studio community?

Tags: c#, debugging, xamarin

If I'm receiving this [image: error]

How can I go about trying to debug my managed code within the function that pops up that error when I place a breakpoint within it?

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, NavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{
  public bool OnNavigationItemSelected(IMenuItem menuItem)
  {
   int id = menuItem.ItemId; //breakpoint here
   if (id == Resource.Id.nav_3DESK)
   {
     string location = "3 Desk";
   }
  }
}
```

I've tried

- enable just my code within the debug options
- creating a sub function to place within this function and debug within
- rolling back to a previous version of visual studio

Comment: What is your actual goal here?  Presumably you are trying to debug this code to diagnose some problem with it - what is that underlying problem?

Comment: @Jason you may be my best bet to solving this issue, I haven't met anyone on any website or discord that knows what to do. my main question was [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76606791/how-can-i-go-about-diagnosing-a-problem-with-visual-studio-being-unable-to-break) I just wanted to ask a separate question about managed code vs native code on this post.

Comment: what I'm getting at is that there are other debugging techniques that don't involve using the IDE debugger.  It's frustrating that its not working in this case, but I personally would switch to a different technique rather than getting bogged down in an IDE issue.

Comment: I'm still kind of new to all of this. If you mean debugging techniques like logging, I understand that they exist. However, I feel that they may not provide the same level of functionality and convenience as a full-fledged debugger integrated into an IDE.  There is actually possibly someone who has solved this error in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344434/xamarin-android-debugging-no-compatible-code-running) but he never clarified how or if he was able to fix his IDE. I want to reach out to him but can't because I don't have 50 points yet.

Comment: You're right, they don't.  But again, how much time do you want to waste getting bogged down in a weird IDE issue?

Comment: I don't want to spend a lot of time on this, but ultimately, if I learn the problem and manage to fix it, I'll be better prepared to tackle it in the future. I've discovered that investing considerable time in solving a coding issue helps solidify the solution in my mind once it's found.

Comment: if you want to post your solution somewhere I can download it I'll give it a quick look to see if I have the same debugging issue

Comment: Good, I see you are trying another angle re [yesterday's question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76606791/199364). We know that thread has managed code in it, because you've set a breakpoint in managed code. Therefore, the debugger is somehow confused about what is going on. I think it isn't correctly determining the breakpoint location. Unfortunately, this means your question - how tell whether thread has managed code or native code - probably won't get you to a solution.

Comment: Some ideas There is a slight possibility that if you first **successfully breakpoint earlier** in the code (MainActivity / app startup), that this will correct some debugger sync issue. Also, stop VS, use task manager to **kill adb.exe**, then try again. BUT my experience has been that there are some mobile UI-code situations that simply can't be correctly breakpointed. **For testing, try calling the method from a button click instead of a menu item. Or inside `Task.Run`, so it is on a background thread.**

Comment: @Jason I have a github I posted it [here](https://github.com/RobGreen490/navBarTest).

Comment: I'm able to step through that method in the debugger.

Comment: I've taken steps to uninstall and reinstall VS once again, nothing seems to work. Is it possible that having an AMD processor is whats causing this error? Especially since others are not experiencing the error?

Comment: I tested on VSMac.  There are a huge number of variables - you could try a different emulator image or different Android device, etc

Comment: I've tried with a few to no avail, tried on another laptop with an emulator to no avail, downloading on a third laptop now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cloned your project and tested it. I met the same problem as yours at first. And then I checked the nuget packages' version in your project and found they are old version.

And the break point will be hit after I updated the nuget packages' versions:

**Update Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat from 1.2.0.5 to 1.6.1.2**

**Update Xamarin.Essentials from 1.6.1 to 1.7.7**

**Update Xamarin.Google.Android.Material from 1.0.0.1 to 1.9.0.1**

The result image:

[image]